# Everything after the & symbol in each line for the rcases environment isn't in math mode, I don't know why

Tags: cases

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{rcases*}
 \left( \nabla^2+k^2\right) & u(\mathbf{r}) =0, \quad r > a \\
& u(\mathbf{r})  =0, \quad r=a.
\end{rcases*} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the material after the `&` alignment points to be treated as being in math mode, use the `rcases` environment, not the `rcases*` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{rcases}
 \left( \nabla^2+k^2\right) & u(\mathbf{r}) =0, \quad r > a \\
& u(\mathbf{r}) =0, \quad r=a.
\end{rcases} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about `rcases`, but do you want the following?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} 
    \left( \nabla^2+k^2\right) \begin{cases}
    u(\mathbf{r}) =0,  & \quad r > a\\
 u(\mathbf{r}) =0, & \quad r=a
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]