# How to give two equations the same equation number?

Tags: equations

I want to write two equations in consecutive lines and I want to give them a single equation number. Often, in notebooks, we write multiple equations in consecutive lines and use a big } sign to allocate only a single equation number. Is it possible to do the same in LaTex? If yes, how do I do that?

I hope I could clearly state my problem.

Comment: No, this is not what I was asking. I want to put one big } at the end of line which covers both equations and at the end of the } the equation number would be given.

Comment: you could use the `rcases` environment as shown in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196634/579

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simpler: load `mathtools` (needless to load `amsmath` in this case: the latter does it for you) and use its `rcases` environment:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{rcases}
        x = y \\
        w = z
    \end{rcases} = xy
  \end{equation
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use align and don't number the first one.

```
\begin{align}
 x &= y \nonumber \\
 w &= z 
 \end{align}
```

You can try this also:

```
  \begin{equation}
    \left.\begin{array}{ll}
        x &= y \\
        w &= z
        \end{array}\right\}
  \end{equation}
```

Comment: this is putting the whole equation in a single line in the pdf. But I wanted separate lines.

Comment: @SamapanBhadury I missed a `\\\`. See the edited anwer.

Comment: Okay, I got what you are trying to tell. But the problem with this format is, the equation number is being implied to the later equation only. Whereas i want to give a set of relations the same equation number. And I think that can be implied by,  using a curly bracket that stretches to multiple lines and is at the end of line to the right of which the equation number can be put. Is this even possible to do in LaTex?

Comment: Thanks. It was the second answer, that I was looking for. Problem solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{array}{c}
A=7\\
B=8
\end{array}
\right\}
\end{equation}
```

Try the above code.

Comment: It is showing the following error:


! Missing delimiter (. inserted).<to be read again>} ...in{array}{c} A=7\ B=8 \end{array} \right}

! Missing delimiter (. inserted).<to be read again>} ...in{array}{c} A=7\ B=8 \end{array} \right}

Comment: \begin{equation} \left. \begin{array}{c} A=7\\ B=8 \end{array} \right\} \end{equation} Try the above code

Comment: @SamapanBhadury it should read `\right\}`, note that dash before the `}`.